# Javascript: Set asp.net button visibility to false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I can't hide my button using javascript, my code is this. (I used an image as a button)

```
<img alt="" src="images/search-icon.png" width="16" height="16" style="display: inline;height:16px;cursor:pointer; width: 16px;" onclick="ViewLookUpPayment('<%=btnShowCorpCode.ClientID %>');" />
```

Here is the code in my javascript.

```
function ViewLookUpPayment(bShow)
{
 var button1 = document.getElementById(bShow);
    button1.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Every time i click on the image this runtime error pops up

[image]

I can't understand why is there a runtime error, Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: Is your function supposed to have a name ?

Comment: @sh1rts Yes it has, someone just edited my question.

Comment: Set the ID mode to static on the button. Set the ID to a known value. Hardcode the javascript call. Open in browser and debug. Verify that you can actually get the element, then unwind until you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img alt="" src="images/search-icon.png" 
width="16" height="16" style="display: 
inline;height:16px;cursor:pointer; width: 16px;" 
onclick="ViewLookUpPayment('<%=btnShowCorpCode.ClientID %>');" />


function ViewLookUpPayment(obj)
{

    document.getElementById(obj).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: `bShow` is a parameter, not a hard coded value.. This would not fix the issue

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar By default in loading the page, btnShowCorpCode's visibility is set to false, that's why I'm stille getting the runtime error even if I tried your code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set 'id' attribute to image tag?

May be "`document.getElementById(bShow)`" returns '`undefined`'. Try checking what "var button1" is.(example: `console.log(button1)`)